# Should close a Formatter that is not holding resources?

Tags: java

I have e.g. a `new Formatter(new StringWriter())`. Should I close the formatter, even if it's not holding any non-memory resources? Closing the StringWriter has no effect anyway.

I could imagine forgetting to do it later if I change the implementation from StringWriter to something else. But on the other hand an unnecessary close just clutters the code.

Comment: "Should" implies a level of obligation I'm not comfortable with. Why *wouldn't* you close it?

Especially since try-with-resources makes it trivial to do so.

Comment: in this particular case I cannot use Java 1.7, so try-with-resources is not available. This would indeed be a clean solution otherwise. As for why wouldn't I, I think that is part of my question; whether there would be compelling reasons not to do it. One that comes to mind is cluttering the code with closes when it's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

No, IMO there is no compelling reason why you *should* close the `Formatter` in this case.

Had you instead written:

```
Writer formatted;
formatted = new StringWriter();
Formatter formatter = new Formatter(formatted, Locale.US);
```

then arguably you *should* call:

```
formatter.close();
```

Even though it will have no effect, since now the `formatted` variable is declared as being of the Interface type `Writer`, which could later be implemented as a genuinely `closable` type such as `PrintWriter`.